# gradle does not create build folder

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a simple gradle project, created by gradle init

The build.gradle file contains the next content:

```
plugins {
    id 'base'
}

tasks.register('copyFile', Copy) {
    from 'desc'
    into "$buildDir/desc"
}
```

running the copyFile or the build task doesn't create a build folder

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce the issue you are having, Am using gradle 6.9 , And tested with 7.5

I tried the following :

- Having desc folder, With any folder/files inside
- calling `gradle copyFile`

This resulted in success and copyed all the files and folders into `/build/desc/`

The task will create both `build folder` + `desc folder` but it will only work if desc is not empty.

Otherwise, It will not execute any commands as there are no files nor folders in `/desc` folder

So, Just make sure the `/desc` is not empty, and call the function with `gradle copyFile`

If you want to link this task with `gradle build` , you can add the following line to your code.

`tasks.named("build") { finalizedBy("copyFile") }`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work even if the folder is not empty, the build folder is not created at all,  I have tried it before in another computer and it worked perfect there.

Comment: I'm using the updated gradle version - 7.5

Comment: Then you can share the log error maybe ?

Comment: I have tried with gradle 7.5, same output , it work like charm, Unless you have an error log to provide, then you have misconfigured gradle setup, I suggest you follow this link to check with the path added https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: there was no error, and now I discovered that there was an mismatch between the actual folder name and the expected